# Add an in/contains into a switch in CoffeeScript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to add in a class when the URL contains a certain string. I have gotten this working by doing a straight when, but this only works the URL is exactly the condition.

For example if the location.search = ?upward_trending=true' this works fine. But if this is an additional filters added to the URL, this breaks.

Please see my code below. How can I convert this to a contains?

```
switch location.search
    when '?upward_trending=true' then $('a.btn.btn-primary.upward_trending').addClass 'active'

    when '?downward_trending=true' then $('a.btn.btn-primary.downward_trending').addClass 'active'

    else $('a.btn.btn-primary.all_scope').addClass 'active'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please find solution below. I switched to using a nested if statement and the indexOf function:

```
if (location.search.indexOf('upward_trending')>=0) then $('a.btn.btn-primary.upward_trending').addClass 'active'
else if (location.search.indexOf('downward_trending')>=0)  then $('a.btn.btn-primary.downward_trending').addClass 'active'
else $('a.btn.btn-primary.all_scope').addClass 'active'
```